# TensorFlow tf.data.Dataset API for medical imaging

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm a student in medical imaging. I have to construct a neural network for image segmentation. I have a data set of 285 subjects, each with 4 modalities (T1, T2, T1ce, FLAIR) + their respective segmentation ground truth. Everything is in 3D with resolution of 240x240x155 voxels (this is BraTS data set).

As we know, I cannot input the whole image on a GPU for memory reasons. I have to preprocess the images and decompose them in 3D overlapping patches (sub-volumes of 40x40x40) which I do with `scikit-image` view_as_windows and then serialize the windows in a TFRecords file. Since each patch overlaps of 10 voxels in each direction, these sums to 5,292 patches per volume. The problem is, with only 1 modality, I get sizes of 800 GB per TFRecords file. Plus, I have to compute their respective segmentation weight map and store it as patches too. Segmentation is also stored as patches in the same file.

And I eventually have to include all the other modalities, which would take nothing less than terabytes of storage. I also have to remember I must also sample equivalent number of patches between background and foreground (class balancing).

So, I guess I have to do all preprocessing steps on-the-fly, just before every training step (while hoping not to slow down training too). I cannot use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors()` since I cannot load everything in RAM. I cannot use `tf.data.Dataset.from_tfrecords()` since preprocessing the whole thing before takes a lot of storage and I will eventually run out.

**The question is :** what's left for me for doing this cleanly with the possibility to reload the model after training for image inference ?

Thank you very much and feel free to ask for any other details.

Pierre-Luc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a method to solve my problem.

I first crop a subject's image without applying the actual crop. I only measure the slices I need to crop the volume to only the brain. I then serialize all the data set images into one TFRecord file, each training example being an image modality, original image's shape and the slices (saved as Int64 feature).

I decode the TFRecords afterward. Each training sample are reshaped to the shape it contains in a feature. I stack all the image modalities into a stack using `tf.stack()` method. I crop the stack using the previously extracted slices (the crop then applies to all images in the stack). I finally get some random patches using `tf.random_crop()` method that allows me to randomly crop a 4-D array  (heigh, width, depth, channel).

The only thing I still haven't figured out is data augmentation. Since all this is occurring in Tensors format, I cannot use plain Python and NumPy to rotate, shear, flip a 4-D array. I would need to do it in the `tf.Session()`, but I would rather like to avoid this and directly input the training handle.

For the evaluation, I serialize in a TFRecords file only one test subject per file. The test subject contains all modalities too, but since there is no TensorFLow methods to extract patches in 4-D, the image is preprocessed in small patches using Scikit-Learn `extract_patches()` method. I serialize these patches to the TFRecords.

This way, training TFRecords is a lot smaller. I can evaluate the test data using batch prediction.

Thanks for reading and feel free to comment !

Comment: Thanks for this post. I was looking for a similar thing but I dont quite understand this line 'I first crop a subject's image without applying the actual crop'?

Comment: @samra I switched to PyTorch after that. Much simpler for research purpose. We started our own libraries Kerosene (https://github.com/banctilrobitaille/kerosene) and SAMITorch (https://github.com/sami-ets/SAMITorch/).